# How to display values from table 1 based on most frequent values from table 2?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables "Clients" and "Tickets"

In "Tickets" I have "ID_Client" column which has: 1,2,3,4,4,2 values.

In "Clients" I have "Name" and "Surname" columns which corresponds to IDs in "Tickets".

Query should display Name and Surname for ID=2 and ID=4

I made a query that works but not completely:

```
SELECT Clients.Name, Clients.Surname
FROM Clients
INNER JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.ID_Client = Tickets.ID_Client
WHERE Tickets.ID_Client = (SELECT ID_Client FROM Tickets
GROUP BY ID_Client ORDER BY Count(*) DESC Limit 1) Limit 1
```

It returns Name and Surname of Client with ID=2 but somehow misses client with ID=4. And I have to add Limit 1 at the end because without it, it displays client with ID=2 two times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly 2 rows, then use `LIMIT 2`:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Surname
FROM Clients c JOIN
     (SELECT t.ID_Client, 
      FROM Tickets t
      GROUP BY t.ID_Client
      ORDER BY Count(*) DESC 
      LIMIT 2
     ) t
     ON c.ID_Client = c.ID_Client;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with @GordonLinoff's solution is it requires an a priori knowledge of how many clients have the maximum entries in the tickets table. What happens when the data becomes 1,2,3,4,4,2,3 and still later 1,2,3,4,4,2,3,4. According to OP initial statement the result after the first would be id=2,3,4 and after the second id=4. What's needed is a solution that determines the necessary number within the SQL. The following does that. Unfortunately, it's an Oracle solution, I don't know MySql, but I believe it has all the below constructs.

Main Query:

```
/* Final desirded columns from clients */
select name, surname 
  from clients
 where 1=1
   and id_client in 
        /* get id_client from ticket and assign a unique row_number for each */   
       (select id_client 
          from (select id_client
                     , row_number() over(partition by id_client
                                             order by id_client) rn
                  from tickets
               )
         where 1=1
           /* select only those having assigned row numbers */
           and rn = 
               /* get the maximum rows for any id_client */   
               (select max(n) 
                  from (select count(*) over(partition by id_client) n 
                          from tickets)));


create table clients (id_client integer, name varchar2(50), surname varchar2(30));
create table tickets (id_ticket integer, id_client integer);

insert into clients (id_client, name, surname) values (1.,'Bob','Meyers');
insert into clients (id_client, name, surname) values (2.,'Bob','Adams');
insert into clients (id_client, name, surname) values (3.,'Lynn','Adams');
insert into clients (id_client, name, surname) values (4.,'William','Wallice');
insert into clients (id_client, name, surname) values (5.,'Julius','Caesar');
insert into clients (id_client, name, surname) values (6.,'William', 'Shakespeare');
insert into clients (id_client, name, surname) values (7.,'Cleopatra', 'Philopator');

insert into tickets (id_ticket, id_client) 
  select rownum, t
    from (select 1 t from dual union all 
          select 2 from dual union all 
          select 3 from dual union all 
          select 4 from dual union all 
          select 4 from dual union all 
          select 2 from dual 
         );
```

RUN MAIN QUERY.

```
insert into tickets (id_ticket, id_client) values ((select max(id_ticket) + 1 from tickets), 3);
```

RUN MAIN QUERY.

```
insert into tickets (id_ticket, id_client) values ((select max(id_ticket) + 1 from tickets), 4);
```

RUN MAIN QUERY.

```
drop table tickets;   
drop table clients;
```

For you Oracle folks I understand there are shorter and/or better solutions, but I wanted to show the derivation at each step. For you MySql perhaps something along the lines of "LIMIT (select...)" I would be interested in the solution.